# CPU info in kernel module

Tags: linux, kernel, kernel-module

I want to know the cpu info inside the kernel module like number of cpus,cores,etc.
Are there ways to find it?
Besides than opening file in kernel module like /proc/cpuinfo.

Comment: Got the following inside the kernel module to get number of cpus 

int i=0;
for_each_online_cpu(i) {

}

Answer (score 1):

Try the `lscpu` command or the `lshw` program.

Answer (score 0):

Check files in `/proc`. You can find some interesting stuff in there about you CPU and processes currently running on you system.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your kernel version, you may find information under `/sys/devices/system/cpu/` as well.